# Modify a line in a particular section of a document with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to use `sed` to modify a Debian [control file](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) to change the dependencies of a particular package.

The file contains metadata for several packages, where entry looks like this:

```
Package: linux-image-generic
Architecture: i386 amd64 armhf arm64 powerpc ppc64el s390x
Section: kernel
Provides: ${dkms:zfs-modules} ${dkms:virtualbox-guest-modules} ${dkms:wireguard-linux-compat-modules}
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, linux-image-${kernel-abi-version}-generic, linux-modules-extra-${kernel-abi-version}-generic [i386 amd64 arm64 powerpc ppc64el s390x], linux-firmware, intel-microcode [amd64 i386], amd64-microcode [amd64 i386]
Recommends: thermald [i386 amd64]
Description: Generic Linux kernel image
 This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel image
 available.

Package: linux-tools-generic
Architecture: i386 amd64 armhf arm64 powerpc ppc64el s390x
Section: kernel
Provides: linux-tools
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, linux-tools-${kernel-abi-version}-generic
Description: Generic Linux kernel tools
 This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel tools
 available.
```

I would like to find the line that matches `Package: linux-image-generic`, then modify the following line that matches `Depends:`, for instance by performing `s/linux-image-/linux-image-unsigned-/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution that modifies the `Depends:` line, but only within the `linux-image-generic` section.

This solution for **GNU sed**, but a slight modification makes it work for BSD sed, noted below.

```
sed '/^Package: linux-image-generic$/,/^$/{/^Depends:/ s/linux-image-/linux-image-unsigned-/}' debian/control
```

It starts with a [range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html#Range-Addresses) that matches from the beginning of the package metadata up to the blank line after the package block.

```
/^Package: linux-image-generic$/,/^$/
```

Then it uses a [`{}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands) to apply a command *within* this range:

```
/^Depends:/ s/linux-image-/linux-image-unsigned-/
```

The first part here, `/^Depends:/`, is a [regular expression address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html#Regexp-Addresses) that selects only the line(s) that begin with `Depends:`.

Lastly, the [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) performs the substitution on the selected line.

---

**BSD sed** (on macOS, etc.) has an additional syntactic rule for function lists `{ ... }`:

> The terminating “}” must be preceded by a newline, and may also be preceded by white space.

We need to insert a newline before the `}`, for example by using the `$'\n'` [ANSI-C string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) in Bash:

```
sed '/^Package: linux-image-generic$/,/^$/{/^Depends:/ s/linux-image-/linux-image-unsigned-/'$'\n''}' debian/control
```

---

As an aside, the path to finding this solution was to research `sed` commands that operate on other file formats with similar syntaxes, like [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` solution you found is perfect. For completeness, with GNU `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^Package: linux-image-generic/ {
  $0 = gensub(/(\nDepends:[^\n]*linux-image-)/,"&unsigned-",1)} 1' file
```

If the input record separator (`RS`) is the empty string records are separated by empty lines. So each section of your file is a record. `gensub` does the substitution.

Comment: For `[\n]*` do you mean `[^\n]*` to match any number of characters except newline?

Comment: Ooops, yes, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Package: linux-image-generic/{:a;n;/Depends:/!ba;s/linux-image-/&unsigned-/}' file
```

Find line containing `Package: linux-image-generic` then continue reading lines until one containing `Depends:` and substitute `linux-image-` with `linux-image-unsigned-`.

N.B. This assumes the package stanza contains `Depends:`, if not, then:

```
sed -E '/Package:/{h;:a;n;/Package:/{h;ba};/Depends/!ba;G
       s/(linux-image-)(.*)\n.*Package: linux-image-generic/\1unsigned-\2/}' file
```